# Emulating variadic templates in Scala

Tags: generics, data-structures, scala, types

Suppose you want to have something like [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_Templates) (the ability to define n type parameters for a generic class) in Scala.

For example you do not want to define `Tuple2[+T1, +T2]` and `Tuple3[+T1, +T2, +T3]` but [`Tuple[T*]`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html).

Are there other options than [HLists](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/2008/08/hlist-in-scala.html) that would support Tuple, Product and Function?

Comment: I assume you could roll your own version of HList, but why?  Can you point to how your envisioned option would be different from an HList?

Comment: The type definition on the user side is a bit complicated for my taste. An ideal solution would allow a more natural type definition Tuple[T1,T2,T3] like the TupleX already do in the Scala libs. Additionally, it should support other types like Function and Product.

Comment: But Scala already offers, and HList uses, some syntactic sugar to reduce that complexity. For instance, see this type definition from the HList link: `val list : Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil = ...`.

Comment: @Daniel This was actually the complexity I was refering to. :-) It is definitely better than `HList[Int, HList[String, HList[Boolean, HNil]]]` but `Tuple3[Int, String, Boolean]` is better from a user's perspective (ignoring the 3 in the name).

Answer (score 6):

At the moment there's no syntactical construct in Scala which allows what you're suggesting. That's also the reason why there are 22 Tuple classes (Tuple2, Tuple3, ..., Tuple22) and also different Function classes (Function0, ...).

Comment: The question implies that there is not a language construct.