# capture types of varargs parameters

Tags: scala

I'd like to define a method accepting varargs, so that I get the types with which it was called even in the case of nulls.

```
def foo(args: Any*) = ....

val s: String = null

foo(1, s) // i'd like to be able to tell in foo that args(0) is Int, args(1) is String
```

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593510/emulating-variadic-templates-in-scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of the original question, I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve (ie, why it must be a variable-length list of arbitrary types), it is difficult to offer an alternative. However, there are two things that came to my mind when I read the question that may be an option for you: [Default argument values](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2075) in combination with named arguments (requires Scala 2.8+), and the [`HList`](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/2008/08/hlist-in-scala.html) data type (less likely).

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `Any` as parameter type you will not be able to determine the type of the arguments statically. You will have to use `instanceof` or pattern matching:

```
def foo(args: Any*) = for (a <- args) a match {
  case i: Int =>
  case s: String =>
  case _ =>
}
```

Unfortuntely, this is not able to handle null values.

If you want static types you will have to use overloading:

```
def foo[A](arg1: A)
def foo[A, B](arg1: A, arg2: B)
def foo[A, B, C](arg1: A, arg2: B, arg3: C)
...
```

Comment: Or use a language that support typed 'varargs' like TypedScheme  :)

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `Any` as type you cannot get the type of the arguments. Type `Any` doesn't have the `getClass` method (it even isn't a reference class at all). See http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128 for more information.

What you can try is this:

```
def foo(args: Any*) = args.map { arg => {
  arg match {
    case reference:AnyRef => reference.getClass.toString
    case null => "null"
}}}

val s: String = null

val result = foo("a", 1, 'c', 3.14, s, new Object, List(1), null)

result.foreach(println)
```

This outputs:

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Character
class java.lang.Double
null
class java.lang.Object
class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
null
```